# C# Generics - Accepting different types

Tags: c#, types, generics

I am trying to write a generic method so I can avoid code duplication. The generic method has to be able to accept one of three different grid view types however I cannot get the following cast to work at the start of the generic method;

```
var grid;

            if (typeof(T) == typeof(GridView))
            {
                grid = (GridView)gridView;
            }
            else if (typeof(T) != typeof(BandedGridView))
            {
                grid = (BandedGridView)gridView;
            }
            else if (typeof(T) != typeof(AdvBandedGridView))
            {
                grid = (AdvBandedGridView)gridView;
            }
            else return;
```

How can I cast "grid" to either of the three types so I can then do something with them. I am still trying to grasp the idea and concept behind Generics.

Comment: Do the three types have the same interface (not interface in a language sense, but in a API sense)?

Comment: You can't declare a var and later initialise it.both should be done in a single step.Just like var a =100

Comment: I am not sure if they all observe the same interface. I currently have three separate methods each accepting a different type but the properties of each type are the same, i.e the methods are identical except for the parameter type

Comment: Try `T grid` instead of `var grid`.  You rarely need to do any casts when you are using generics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `BrandedGridView` and `AdvBrandedGridView` both inherit from `GridView` you can add a constraint to your generic

`...<T> where T : GridView`

If not you can use `Convert.ChangeType`:

Try Convert.ChangeType:

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(GridView))
{
    var grid = (GridView)Convert.ChangeType(gridView, typeof(GridView));
}
elseif (typeof(T) == typeof(BrandedGridView))
{
    var grid = (BrandedGridView)Convert.ChangeType(gridView, typeof(BrandedGridView));
}
```

Comment: What if BrandedgridView is not compatible with gridview?What will Convert.ChangeType return in that case?

Comment: ChangeType is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: The three types are all compatible

Comment: @Srinivas Reddy Thatiparthy it will throw an exception.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx for details.

Comment: @Josata - glad to hear it, although if all three share a common ancestry, adding the constraint and just casting between them would save the overhead of reflection in `Convert.ChangeType`

Answer (score 1):

You want to constrain type T to something (likely GridView as 2 other types are likely derive from it) so C# knows what method the T has, otherwise it is just of type Object.

```
public class MyClass<T> where T : GridView
```

Please read article about generic on MSDN to get more details - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(VS.80).aspx#csharp_generics_topic4

Note: As mentioned above C# is not JavaScript and "var" does not mean "a type" it is just shorter way to declare object of type of the right side. I.e. in var my = new List() var is synonim for List.

Answer (score 0):

"methods are identical except for the parameter type"

I think you should just make a new method that has the different parameter type of the view as the actual parameters. They're the ones that are different after all.